# Stick header causes page jumps when short page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My sticky header causes the page to jump when the page isn't so long. On pages with large amounts of scrolling it works completely fine but when it is just a small amount it jumps it back to the point of stick. I think it gets trapped in between the point it sticks and the transition part.

```
#header{
    width: 100%; 
    height:100%;
}

.headertwo{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 48px !important;
    background: url(../images/work/topsky.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

#header_stick{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

#header_stick img{
    margin-top: 1px;
    width: 120px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    height: 51px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: white;
    opacity:0.9;
    z-index: 14;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}

.stick img {

    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
    -o-transition: all .25s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
    transition: all .25s ease;
}


$(function() {
 jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
if(top>42) // height of float header
jQuery('#header_stick').addClass('stick');
else
 jQuery('#header_stick').removeClass('stick');
    })

});


<div id="headertwo">
    <div id="intro">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="header_stick">

    <div class="nav-container">

        <div class="nav-logo feature">

            <a href="index.html#anchor" class="transition">
            </a>
            <div class="nav-logo-img"><img src="images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div class="nav-logo-text">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-menu">
            <div class="nav-link contact"><a href="contact.html" class="transition">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-link about"><a href="about.html" class="active transition">About</a>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-link work"><a href="index.html#anchor" class="transition">Work</a>
            </div>
            <button id="trigger-overlay" type="button">Menu</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="overlay overlay-hugeinc">
        <button type="button" class="overlay-close">Close</button>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html#anchor">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>


<div class="width-container">
    <div class="line">
    </div>

    <div class="project contact-padding">
        <div class="column-one">
            <div class="header-container">
                <div class="header">About
                </div>
                <div class="subtitle">Subtitle
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="column-two">

                <div class="about-body-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis et fringilla sapien, eget feugiat justo. Aenean gravida libero ac dolor sagittis, in eleifend tortor lacinia. Quisque at lectus in ex imperdiet convallis. Morbi leo nisi, suscipit eu semper non, mattixs non velit. Duis commodo sem nibh, vitae pharetra purus feugiat sit amet. Etiam suscipit commodo nibh. Suspendisse nisi augue, iaculis rutrum ultricies nec, volutpat quis justo. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Etiam imperdiet non diam sit amet suscipit.
                </div>

        </div>

    </div>



</div>

<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-half footer-half-first">
    </div>
    <div class="footer-half footer-half-second">
        <div class="footer-contents">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the CSS you provided might be missing something, but I think I understand what's happening. When you scroll the page passed the height of your header, you set it to `position:fixed`. By doing this, you remove some of the height of the page, which means `jQuery(window).scrollTop()` changes (scrollTop is now lower than your header height - 42).

This is what causes it to constantly flicker between `addClass("stick")` and `removeClass("stick")`, causing that "jumpy" feeling.

You need to add a placeholder that's the same height as the header when you stick the header to the top. With the CSS you gave me, that height was `80px`. So I added padding to the top of your content to compensate.

```
$(function() {
     jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
         var top = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

         if(top>42) { // height of float header
             jQuery('#header_stick').addClass('stick');
             jQuery('.width-container').css("paddingTop", "80px");
         } else {
             jQuery('#header_stick').removeClass('stick');
             jQuery('.width-container').css("paddingTop", "0px");
         }
    });
});
```

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/hzn6map1/

Comment: sounds like the problem you identified is probably true

Comment: That's exactly it. I did experience a jump down when on my longer pages! Thanks so much. I didn't even think of that.

Comment: @Scott Rowell you saved my day, thank a lot